# Cannot connect my AWS api gateway with my local host

Tags: reactjs, xml, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

When I try to submit my form using from local host reactjs it showing console error:

> "Missing required key 'TableName' in params", code:
> "MissingRequiredParameter", time: "2021-01-06T06:40:42.102Z"}.

Using AWS amplify for frontend and backend.

The post call is:

```js
app.post('/contact', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req);
    var params = {
        Tablename: process.env.STORAGE_FORMTABLE_NAME,
        Item: {
            id: id(),
            name: req.body.name,
            email: req.body.email,
            phonenumber: req.body.phonenumber,
            address: req.body.address,
            message: req.body.message
        }
    }
    docClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) res.json({
            err
        })
        else res.json({
            success: 'Contact created successfully!'
        })
    })
});
```

Comment: Could you include the Lamda function you used?

Comment: @yudhiesh   i coudnt send complete function..

Comment: Include how you are making the POST request.

Comment: app.post('/contact', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req);

  var params = {
    Tablename: process.env.STORAGE_FORMTABLE_NAME,
    Item: {
      id: id(),
      name: req.body.name,
      email: req.body.email,
      phonenumber: req.body.phonenumber,
      address: req.body.address,
      message: req.body.message
    }
  }
   docClient.put(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) res.json({ err })
    else res.json({ success: 'Contact created successfully!' })
  })
});

Comment: Is `STORAGE_FORMTABLE_NAME` a string in your `.env` file?

Comment: yes, its showing env type{string} under tablename

Comment: Could it be that in your code you have `Tablename` but the parameter missing is `TableName`? Check your casing

Comment: do i have to provide the table name which is present in dynamodb... ? it should match?..

Answer (score 2):

Try changing Tablename to TableName (capital N) in your params like this:

```
var params = {
    TableName: process.env.STORAGE_FORMTABLE_NAME,
    Item: {
        id: id(),
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        phonenumber: req.body.phonenumber,
        address: req.body.address,
        message: req.body.message
    }
}
```